# Add all properties of my JavaBean as columns by default in Vaadin 8 grid?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin8

Is there a way in Vaadin 8 Grid to automatically display all the JavaBean-pattern properties as columns in the table? And automatically label each column header with the name of the property?

In the *Binding to Data* section of [this page in the Vaadin guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html), we see this code where we must explicitly specify which properties to use as columns in the grid.

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(people);
grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("Name");
grid.addColumn(Person::getBirthYear).setCaption("Year of birth");
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible by passing in the bean type as a parameter to the grids constructor:

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class);
```

---

**JavaDoc:**

> ```
> /**
>  * Creates a new grid that uses reflection based on the provided bean type
>  * to automatically set up an initial set of columns. All columns will be
>  * configured using the same {@link Object#toString()} renderer that is used
>  * by {@link #addColumn(ValueProvider)}.
>  *
>  * @param beanType
>  *            the bean type to use, not <code>null</code>
>  * @see #Grid()
>  * @see #withPropertySet(PropertySet)
>  */
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can set all columns at once, using a `com.vaadin.data.PropertySet`:

```
PropertySet<Person> ps = ...;
Grid<Person> g = Grid.withPropertySet(ps);`
```

For a reflection based `PropertySet` based on the JavaBean properties, Vaadin provides:

```
BeanPropertySet.get(Person.class)
```

For standard use cases (where the default BeanPropertySet is good enough), you can just simple use (as already answered by @JDC):

```
new Grid<>(Person.class)
```